# How to change the numerical values in multiple columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set something like this:

```
df <- tribble(
        ~X,     ~Y,    ~Z,
        "a",     0,     2,  
        "b",     5,     0, 
        "c",     0,     0, 
        "d",     3,     1, 
        "e",     0,     2, 
)
```

Now, I want to revalue the values in the column of Y and Z if they are zero. So, I basically use the function of `case_when`. But this returned the values `NA` if they are non-zero.

```
df_desired <- df %>% 
  mutate(Y = case_when(Y == 0 ~ 0.0001),
         Z = case_when(Z == 0 ~ 0.0001))
```

I was wondering what I am missing the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `case_when` default values i.e `TRUE` returns `NA` unless specified.  According to `?case_when`

> This function allows you to vectorise multiple if_else() statements. It is an R equivalent of the SQL CASE WHEN statement. If no cases match, NA is returned.

Here, the no cases match is returning `NA` unless the default condition with `TRUE` is provided

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  
   mutate(Y = case_when(Y == 0 ~ 0.0001, TRUE ~ Y),  
          Z = case_when(Z == 0 ~ 0.0001, TRUE ~ Z))
```

which can be made more compact with `mutate_at`

```
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(Y, Z), ~ case_when(. == 0 ~ 0.0001, TRUE ~ .))
```

Also, in this case, `replace` may be more compact

```
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(Y, Z), ~ replace(., .== 0, 0.0001))
```

Or may be arithmetic

```
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Y, Z), ~  . + (. == 0) * 0.0001)
```

@Junitar's suggested to check the type if we want to apply on `numeric` columns

```
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric,  ~ case_when(. == 0 ~ 0.0001, TRUE ~ .))
```

Comment: Given @zineda's example, it might even be more appropriate/robust to use `mutate_if(is_double, fun)` so that `mutate` is not dependant on the column names.